# Calling Javascript function from external file when loading html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load a function named `james()` from a Javascript file named `hello.js` which is added as an external file to `index.html`.

My problem is when the function james is declared inside `$(document).ready(function())`, it just says that 'james function is undefined' and is not called. How can I call function declared inside document.ready using onload?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload= "james()">
         <script src=hello.js>
</body>
</html>
```

hello.js javascript file

```
function mountApp{

   $(document).ready(function(){

      function james(){
      alert("how can i get call ,when html page is loaded");
     }
 });
}
```

Comment: Hi @bbmac, I think that you need to add jquery into your HTML before `hello.js` script, since `ready` is a jquery function

Comment: The issue is because functions called from `on*` attributes  need to be in global scope. It's partly for this reason they should be avoided. Just call `james()` from within the `document.ready()` (or `$(window).on('load')`) handler directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "james" function does not exist in the correct scope. It is declared inside the "ready" event listener and only exists inside the listener scope. After that, it won't be available anymore.

You cannot do what you are trying to do. Functions cannot be used outside of the scope they were declared in.
Move the function to the global scope instead.

```
function mountApp{

   $(document).ready(function(){
     // You can call the function from here
     james();
   });
}

function james(){
  alert("how can i get call ,when html page is loaded");
}
```

Now, I don't see why you would be adding an event listener "onready" inside a function, because function calls will only be executed after the DOM is ready, so it will never trigger.

Comment: "function calls will only be executed after the DOM is ready" — As a general statement, that isn't true. Function calls will be executed whenever they happen. In this particular case, the function call is done in the load event handler, so that call will wait until after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

true method is, you create function outside document.ready function and then call

```
function james()
{
  alert("how can i get call ,when html page is loaded");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 james();
)};
```